# Call to open() to create a file fails if the file exists

Tags: c, file, unix

I'm trying to create a C code which will create a file for which I can read or write from/to. This file can already exist, or need to be created from scratch. If it already exists within the directory, I want it to created from scratch, in other words delete all the contents.

```
 FD = open("p.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
```

I've tried using that for the time being. I encounter a problem though. If the file doesn't exist, it creates it and returns a positive file descriptor.

If the file however already exists, a -1 FD is returned. So I must be missing a flag?

I assumed O_TRUNC would be enough to clear the contents of a file?

Comment: You might not have permission to modify it. Check strerror().

Comment: Right, their was a issue with permission. I had no "read or write" permissions. I changed it to full permission and it was fine after. If I delete the file from the directory and compile and run...i stil come under the same issue

Comment: Read the man page for `open`. When you specify `O_CREAT`, there's a third argument, after the flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FD = open("p.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
```

Comment: Thanks, i used "S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR" after reading a earlier comment!

Answer (score 0):

When a Unix call returns -1, check the value of the `errno` variable. It contains the reason for the error. Don't speculate as to what might be the problem until you've seen the error code. You can call `strerror` or `perror` to get a message describing the numerical value stored in `errno`.

Also, as others have noted, when you pass `O_CREAT` to `open`, you must pass a third argument which determines the file's permission if it's created. (If you don't )

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    int fd = open("p.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("opening p.txt");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* … */
}
```